# Sorting Lucene.net search results in a specific order

Tags: c#, sorting, lucene.net

We use Lucene.Net for a product search on a website. For a category we fetch all products which have an exact match for field category with the categories unique id.

For one client we have a requirement for the products to be listed in a specific order when there are no other criteria. These are arranged per category and a product can appear in multiple categories. So we can't just have an global order field. My first thought for a solution that would work with out of the box Lucene.net was to have a field for each category on the products which will contain the sort order. But this won't scale well if there are lots of categories.

Once a search term is entered or a facet is selected we then order the products by the best match using the regular scoring system. But when there is just a term query for a category we'd like to be able to sort them by a specific order.

Is there a way of doing this with a custom scorer that could accept a list of IDs or similar and score them based on that? Essentially what we need to do is order the Lucene search results by an order specified in a database table or other external source.

Answer (score 0):

This not an out of the box solution, we're using Open Search Server which I believe is a wrapper around the same search engine.  We had similar requirements along with a whole bunch of other requirements (complex filtering/permissions/security) which drove us to cache the results from the search engine in a database (it would page through the results on a background thread and persist them to the DB), after that you can do joins between the search results and other tables in your db and do indexed sorts to your hearts content.  Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd looked at something like this but was hoping for a solution that didn't involve generating the results and putting them somewhere to sort, but could be done just with the index

Answer (score 0):

In a similar solution for a high traffic website, we did the sorting ourselves. Lucene would find the results, then we sorted them on the fly and gave a paged result. Most .net Sorting algorithms are efficient enough, but we used a Radix Sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to get it to perform to our liking.

Comment: Wouldn't that require the rank field to be in the search index? I was hoping for a neat solution that would mean that I don't have a field for each category to sort by, but instead sort the index by an arbitrary order from an external source, for example a database table

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Elasticsearch which is based on Lucene, and the way I'm doing it , is to boost the fields that you want the elements to be ordered by.

a Second method is pure Javascript http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ , the elements are rendered on the fly then ordered by javascript , please see some examples , It might help you! 
EDIT : 
ALL Relies on your logic : if you want to order by category : boost the category !

Scenario : user ask for category : Mobile , with normal scoring system let's say you have this results 
 : 
user looking for nokia

product1 : category :car , title: nokia car ,score :3.34
product2 : category :appliance , title : cool nokia appliance : score 3.32
product3 : category :mobile , title : Nokia 3310  : score 2.32
product4 : category :mobile , title : Nokia 6600 : score 2.31

now if the field category is boosted , You will have this :
product1 : category :mobile , title: Nokia 3310 ,score :6.35
product2 : category :mobile , title : Nokia 6600 : score 6.32
product3 : category :appliance , title : other nokia  : score 2.32
product4 : category :car , title : nokia car : score 2.31

scores I used are arbitrary

Comment: But how do I include the field I want to sort by in the index, do I include one field for each category? What if there are 1000 categories?

Comment: Do you want to order or group by ?

Comment: Just to order the results, by an arbitrary order, so if I want all products in category X, they should be displayed in the order specified in a database table. Those same products could be in category Y but in a different order, so I can't just have a rank field in the index.

Comment: They will not be displayed in the order specified in the database order , but in the index order , and if you're using a cluster in Lucene , it's more difficult to know the order. 
But back to the bright side , if you have a field called category , and the user asks for mobile category , if the category field is boosted , they will list you all the product in the mobile category in first , ordered on te fly

Comment: Ok, I have a problem with pure JS methods as we need to support users with JS disabled. The other issue is I only want products from the mobile category, no other products and I want them in a specific order, the order that is defined in a database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52593/discussion-between-sekai-and-steve-temple)